# Error on drawing Fibonacci in web

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

Currently I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/8a7fdg3d/3/) from Blindman67 which draws [Golden spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) figure 1(see image below).

```
function renderSpiral(pointA, pointB, turns){
var dx, dy, rad, i, ang, cx, cy, dist, a, c, angleStep, numberTurns, nTFPB, scale, styles;
// clear the canvas
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)

// spiral stuff
a = 1;         // the larger this number the larger the spiral
c = 1.358456;   // constant See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral
angleStep = Math.PI/20;  // set the angular resultion for drawing
numberTurns = 6;  // total half turns drawn
nTFPB = 2;   //  numberOfTurnsForPointB is the number of turns to point
                 // B should be integer and describes the number off
                 // turns made befor reaching point B

// get the ang from pointA to B
ang = Math.atan2(pointB.y-pointA.y,pointB.x-pointA.x);
// get the distance from A to B
dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pointB.y-pointA.y,2)+Math.pow(pointB.x-pointA.x,2));
if(dist === 0){
    return;  // this makes no sense so exit as nothing to draw
}
// get the spiral radius at point B
rad = Math.pow(c,ang + nTFPB * 2 * Math.PI); // spiral radius at point2

// now just need to get the correct scale so the spiral fist to the
// constraints requiered.
scale = dist / rad;


// ajust the number of turns so that the spiral fills the canvas
while(Math.pow(c,Math.PI*numberTurns)*scale < ctx.canvas.width){
    numberTurns += 2;
}

// set the scale, and origin to centre
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, pointA.x, pointA.y)

// make it look nice create some line styles


// first just draw the line A-B
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 2 * ( 1 / scale); // because it is scaled invert the scale
                                  // can calculate the width requiered
// ready to draw                               
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0)        // start at center
ctx.lineTo((pointB.x-pointA.x)*(1/scale),(pointB.y-pointA.y)*(1/scale) );  // add line
ctx.stroke();  // draw it all

// Now draw the sporal. draw it for each style 
styles.forEach( function(style) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = style.colour;
    ctx.lineWidth = style.width * ( 1 / scale); // because it is scaled invert the scale
                                                // can calculate the width requiered
    // ready to draw                               
    ctx.beginPath();
    for( i = 0; i <= Math.PI *numberTurns; i+= angleStep){
        dx = Math.cos(i);  // get the vector for angle i
        dy = Math.sin(i);
        var rad = Math.pow(c, i);  // calculate the radius
        if(i === 0) {                
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0)        // start at center
        }else{
            ctx.lineTo(dx * rad, dy * rad );  // add line
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();  // draw it all
});
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset tranfrom to default;
}
```

What I want to obtain is figure 2 (see image below).

[image]

Q1. **How can I change mine spiral so line `AB` will fit between first and second screw while `A` is the start of spiral?**

You can also refer to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232159/how-to-make-a-drawing-of-fibonacci-in-javascript) for better understanding of my problem.

Comment: @Spektre If you will compare Figure 1 and Figure 2, then you can identify what's the problem.

Comment: A and B are points to create a line on which the spiral depends

Comment: that does not explain anything. 1. left image does not correspont to your output. 2. you want to have spiral screws with `|AB|` distance to each other that is obvious but what is the |AB|? it is not constant (at least not in the image bu you show only 2 screws so I may be wrong anyway you should specify this...) so what exactly is it ? how it depend on angle or distance from the start of spiral etc ... without this are booth of your question unanswerable

Comment: @Spektre Sorry for not being clear. Point A will also be the start of the spiral. Basically my only problem is how to make the spiral drawing start on exactly Point A so that the line |AB| will only intersect at the spiral twice.

Comment: and are spiral and `|AB|` related to each other or not? for example is `AB` normal to spiral at `A` ? what is the spiral equation? if you change size of `AB` does shape of spiral change or just rotate?

Comment: @Spektre the spiral and |AB| are related in such a way that if you change the length of |AB| then Spiral will also change.

Comment: so is the distance between screws (all of them) constant and equal to `|AB|` ?  And where does the Fibonacci go ...

Comment: then the equation is present in the fiddle

Comment: In the fiddle as you move the line, same happens to the spiral.

Comment: I added the update to the question with a fiddle that shows the solution as close as possible to the one you are asking here. The line A-B does not cross the spiral in that solution until you wind it up to do so. The fiddle you are after has annotated line displaying the angle from the start and the distance from the origin.

Comment: I see you have the wrong fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/8a7fdg3d/3/ is what you are after,

Comment: @Blindman67 I did that on purpose

Comment: @ThomasM. added answer ... Just got an idea that it is possible that the distortion is caused by the fact that point `A` is not precisely the start point of spiral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the properties you need you need to adjust your spiral like following:

1. **choose the right angular position of the line `AB`**

   I choose `1.5*M_PI [rad]` for `A` and `3.5*M_PI [rad]` for `B` (on unrotated spiral)
2. **rotate your spiral by angle of your `AB` line**

   that is easy just add the angle to the final polar `->` cartesian coordinates conversion and that will rotate entire spiral so computed angular positions of `A,B` on spiral will match the real points `AB` direction
3. **rescale your spiral to match the `AB` size**

   So compute the radiuses for angular points `A`,`B` positons on spiral and then compute the `scale=|AB|-(r(b)-r(a))`. Now just multiply this to compute radius of each rendered point ...

**I played a bit with the golden ratio and spiral a bit and here is the result**

[image: golden spiral]

- `Yellow` spiral is approximation by quarter circle arcs
- `Aqua` is the Golden spiral

As you can see they do not match so much (this is with `ratio*0.75` to make them more similar but it should be just `ratio`) Either I have a bug somewhere, or the origin of spiral is shifted (but does not look like it) or I have wrong ratio constant `ratio = 0.3063489` or the Golden rectangles are introducing higher floating round errors then I taught or I am missing something stupid.

Here the C++ source code so you can extract what you need:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Math.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool _redraw=false;                     // just signal to repaint window after spiral change
double Ax,Ay,Bx,By;                     // mouse eddited points
double gr=0.75;                         // golden spiral ratio scale should be 1 !!!

void GoldenSpiral_draw(TCanvas *can)    // GDI draw
    {
    double a0,a,b,l,x,y,r=5,ratio;

    // draw AB line
    can->Pen->Color=clWhite;
    can->MoveTo(Ax,Ay);
    can->LineTo(Bx,By);
    // draw A,B points
    can->Pen->Color=clBlue;
    can->Brush->Color=clAqua;
    can->Ellipse(Ax-r,Ay-r,Ax+r,Ay+r);
    can->Ellipse(Bx-r,By-r,Bx+r,By+r);
    // draw golden ratio rectangles
    can->Pen->Color=clDkGray;
    can->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    ratio=1.6180339887;
    a=5.0; b=a/ratio; x=Ax; y=Ay;
    y-=0.5*b; x-=0.5*b; // bias to match real golden spiral
    can->Rectangle(x,y,x+a,y+b); y-=a;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
        can->Rectangle(x,y,x+a,y+a);             b=a; a*=ratio; x-=a;
        can->Rectangle(x,y,x+a,y+a); y+=a;       b=a; a*=ratio;
        can->Rectangle(x,y,x+a,y+a); x+=a; y-=b; b=a; a*=ratio;
        can->Rectangle(x,y,x+a,y+a); x-=b;       b=a; a*=ratio; y-=a;
        }
    // draw circle arc approximation of golden spiral
    ratio=1.6180339887;
    a=5.0; b=a/ratio; x=Ax; y=Ay; r=10000; y-=a;
    y-=0.5*b; x-=0.5*b; // bias to match real golden spiral
    can->Pen->Color=clYellow;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
        can->Arc(x-a,y,x+a,y+a+a,+r, 0, 0,-r);             b=a; a*=ratio; x-=a;
        can->Arc(x,y,x+a+a,y+a+a, 0,-r,-r, 0); y+=a;       b=a; a*=ratio;
        can->Arc(x,y-a,x+a+a,y+a,-r, 0, 0,+r); x+=a; y-=b; b=a; a*=ratio;
        can->Arc(x-a,y-a,x+a,y+a, 0,+r,+r, 0); x-=b;       b=a; a*=ratio; y-=a;
        }
    can->Brush->Style=bsSolid;

    // compute golden spiral parameters
    ratio=0.3063489*gr;
    x=Bx-Ax;
    y=By-Ay;
    l=sqrt(x*x+y*y);    // l=|AB|
    if (l<1.0) return;  // prevent domain errors
    a0=atan2(-y,x);     // a=atan2(AB)
    a0+=0.5*M_PI;       // offset so direction of AB matches the normal
    a=1.5*M_PI; r=a*exp(ratio*a); b=r;
    a+=2.0*M_PI; r=a*exp(ratio*a); b=r-b;
    b=l/r;              // b=zoom of spiral to match AB screw distance
    // draw golden spiral
    can->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    can->MoveTo(Ax,Ay);
    for (a=0.0;a<100.0*M_PI;a+=0.001)
        {
        r=a*b*exp(ratio*a); if (r>512.0) break;
        x=Ax+r*cos(a0+a);
        y=Ay-r*sin(a0+a);
        can->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- You can ignore the golden ratio rectangles and circular arcs ...
- change the drawings based on `can->` to your gfx API. It is just **GDI** `Canvas`

Hard to say if your spiral is correct ... you can check with the golden ratio rectangles (as I did). If you got correct spiral then just apply the bullets **#1,#2,#3** to it and you should be fine.

Comment: After some thinking the inconsistency between yellow and aqua spirals are most likely due to floating point rounding errors. As my Golden Rectangles are growing from small size to bigger using only 11 digit ratio constant the error is propagated increasingly ... visible difference is after 7 recursions. So may be shrinking/cutting would be better ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle which I believe gives you the output your looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/8a7fdg3d/4/

The main problem was starting the spiral from 0 results in the initial straight line.

Starting the spiral from 1 removes this part of the graph and then you just had to adjust the starting point of your black |AB| line.

This was done by adjusting

```
for( i = 0; i <= Math.PI *numberTurns; i+= angleStep)
```

to

```
for( i = 1; i <= Math.PI *numberTurns; i+= angleStep)
```

to change the starting point of the spiral, then changing

```
// ready to draw                               
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0)        // start at center
```

to

```
  // ready to draw                               
  ctx.beginPath();        
  dx = Math.cos(1);  // get the vector for angle i
  dy = Math.sin(1);
  var rad = Math.pow(c, 1);  // calculate the radius
  ctx.moveTo(dx * rad, dy * rad )        // start at center
```

to make your |AB| line match up.

Comment: There is a transition problem when you move it around